# Pairing components of a character vector according to substrings whithin them

Tags: r, string, substring

Pairing components of a character vector according to substrings whithin them, which are identified by the position of a common marker character.

My 'pedestrian' attempts to a solution with str_locate_all() and str_sub()
have become so akward that finally I ask for help.

Starting with a vector of character strings, tst1, I want to construct the vector tst2 below. Each component in tst1 contains 3 marker characters '_' (underscore).

In the wanted vector tst2 each string is paired with a second one from tst1
where the two characters following the position of the second '_' (underscore) match, e.g. "Sa", "DE", "F3", "KN".

Any string in tst1 is to be omitted for which no corresponding matching component exists. A second result string such as tstu below would be a "nice to have".

Example:

```
tst1 <- c("unprd3", "L2_T_SaW20_3,3", "Zwo-2_7_F3W19_3,3", 
         "Le2_2_KNW20_3,3", "Zw_22_DEW18_3", "Zf_19_SaW16_3,3", 
         "Zf2_2_KNK20_2,3", "Lvi_7_F3W18_3,3", "unpaired1", 
         "Zf2_2_KNK20_2,3","unprd2")
```

Wanted:

```
tst2 <- c("L2_T_SaW20_3,3",   "Zf_19_SaW16_3,3"
        ,"Lv-2_T_DEW20_3,3", "Zw_22_DEW18_3"
        ,"Lvi_7_F3W18_3,3",  "Zwo-2_7_F3W19_3,2"
        ,"Le2_2_KNW20_3,3",  "Zf2_2_KNK18_2,3")
        
tstu <- c("unpaired1", "unprd2", "unprd3")
```

- Solved (after streamlining my 'pedestrian' way), i.e., with 2 nested for() loops, 5 str_locate(), 3 is.na(), 2 which() and 1 str_locate_all() calls. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language that you are using.